# Django urls -Reverse for 'url name' not found

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-urls

I have a Django application called polls.
I'm trying to use a form in a template that it's action is calling to another url.
mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.call_login, name='call_login'),
    url(r'^homepage/$', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

login.html:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

The error I got:
NoReverseMatch:

> Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or
>   pattern name.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your main url pattern

from

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

to this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and template form

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="{% url 'polls:login' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="user"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```